# div shown with jquery is cropped

Tags: jquery, css, height, truncated

I'm trying to fight a strange behaviour - and any help is appreciated.

I have a long and complex HTML page with general structure about like this:

```
+------------------------------------------+
| Page header                              |
+-----------------------------+------------+
|                             |  Right     |
| Main content                |  Column    |
|                             |            |
+-----------------------------+------------+
```

In the "main content", all the action is taking place.  One of the thing that may happen is on a user's button click, a div with `absolute` position, which is initially invisible, is being displayed and its content is populated using AJAX (i.e. I don't know in advance how much content there is).

This works fine if the overall `height` of this div ends up smaller than the available height of the "main content".  If however this "popup" div ends up being long due to a lot of content, then it's truncated at the bottom of "Main content" div.  As there's nothing below, I can't even scroll down to see all the content of the popup.  I would want the "main content" to grow to accommodate the entire height of the popup and the page to be scrollable all the way to the bottom of the popup, but this is not happening.

Here is CSS for my "main content":

```
.content {
    width: 770px;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

And here's the CSS for the popup:

```
#popupedit {
    background-color: #f1f0ec;
    width: 770px;
    z-index: 100001;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    display: none;
}
```

In HTML, `popupedit` is a direct child of `content`.  There's no height or max-height restriction anywhere in the chain.  So why isn't "content" growing to accommodate the "popup"?

Comment: Try making `overflow-y:` visible in `.content`

Comment: This possible could be related.  Unfortunately, for other reasons, I cannot remove "overflow-y: hidden".  However, to my knowledge, this only has effect if I'm explicitly controlling the height of the parent.  In my case, the height is always "auto"

Comment: Absolute positioned elements do not add to the natural height or width of their parents. That is why your containing div does not adjust to the size. There are some hacks for these sort of things, but I would recommend moving the popup outside, preferably append it directly to the body element. This will also make your solution more OLD-IE-safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly solve this by removing the absolute positioning and using a different technique (i.e. floats) to position the popup.  Let me guess, `position: absolute` is required too? :) If so, then there's still hope: You can resize the content div with JavaScript after the content has loaded.

```
$(".content").css("min-height", $("#popupedit").height()+"px");
```

Of course this would have to run after the popup has fully loaded, and you should probably undo the resize after the popup goes away:

```
$(".content").css("min-height", "");
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking.  Of course, it's a bit more complicated, because that content contains images and what I get via AJAX is just the URL's of the images.  I won't know the real height of the popup until all the images are loaded as well. :)

Comment: Then after running the above code on the just-inserted content, bind it to the `load` event of all images in the popup: `$("#popupedit img").load(updateFunction);`.  The resizing code is fast and idempotent; you can run it as many times as necessary (though you may need to add a check so that it won't run after the popup is closed).

Comment: Aha! that was the part that I was missing: binding the `load` of images.  Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're creating the popup within the .content div.

This has overflow-y: hidden which will hide any overflow.

Try moving the popup out of the content div.

Comment: I can't move it outside.  As for the "overflow-y: hidden", my understanding is that this only applies when I explicitly set "height" or "max-height" on the parent.  Otherwise, the parent's height is supposed to be adjusted to fit children.

Comment: Why can't you move it? How are you making the popup visible when needed?

Comment: I simply don't have control over anything outside the "main content".  The way the layout engine is designed, the header is output first, followed by the right column.  Then the main content is inserted.  Finally, a global footer follows.  The engine takes care of all the layout and simply inserts my page (which is a content that goes inside "div" that is opened and closed from the parent) where needed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove overflow-y: hidden; and it should work. Also I would recommend giving popupedit fixed height

Edit: Ok try this hack

JS:

```
var hh = document.getElementById('popupedit').offsetHeight;
document.getElementById('fix').style.height = hh + "px";
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    width: 770px;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: auto
}
#popupedit {
    background-color: #f1f0ec;
    width: 770px;
    z-index: 100001;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

#fix { width: 770px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class = "content">
    <div id = "popupedit">
        <p>Something important</p>                
    </div>
    <div id = "fix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't remove "overflow-y: hidden" for various reason.  My understanding is that "overflow-y: hidden" only applies when height or max-height is set on the parent. Otherwise, the parent should grow to accommodate children.  Fixed height to the popup is definitely out of the question, as the content can be anywhere between 100 and 1000 pixels in height and the popup has its own background, which should only be visible where the content is.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the `position:relative;` of .content. This isn't needed anyway (unless you need it for something that you have not said). This is a great misunderstanding. A lot of people use `position: relative;` for almost all elements. That's not needed AT ALL.

In this case it can even cause trouble, because `#popupedit` will now position itself absolutely to its parent and not to the window. What I suggest is, deleting `position: relative;`, giving the pop-up a static `width` an calculating its horizontal position with jQuery to centre it. Also get rid of `top: 0;` and `left: 0;`

Then you add this snippet of code to the code you call for popping-it-up, or in a seperate file (doesn't really matter):

```
$("#popupedit ").css({
    left: ($(window).width() - $('.className').outerWidth())/2,
    top: ($(window).height() - $('.className').outerHeight())/2
});​
```

Comment: You seem to completely misunderstand my question. This is exactly why I have "position: relative" on the parent: because I need the absolutely positioned div to be positioned absolutely to its parent and not the window.  And I don't want to resize the popup - I need the popup to be as big as it needs to be - and have the parent adjust its height to match.

Comment: Well, then you are quite missing the point of a 'pop up'. Anyway, please provide a test case.